# How do I validate process page when user save as current form page?

Tags: php

1. Example form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and I save this
   page to desktop.
2. Then I edit the `action="/questions/ask/submit"` to full URL and submit.

Question

On the process form how do I validate that `submit` process will return to error page or denied if situation like this?

Comment: You mean you want to prevent external submissions to your page.

Comment: Yes and sometime user will edit value of hidden input. Let's say amount before redirect to payment page etc..

Comment: You're not looking at this right. The price of a product is **not** a user input. It's not something to be inputted by the user, it's something to be **determined** by the server. You shouldn't have a hidden input containing the product price. Only the product ID, and take the price from a database.

Comment: Thanks @Truth & Quentin. Great point to fix my hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to prevent someone from submitting a form from an external site (not your server).

The solution is quite simple, add a session variable to someone accessing your form page, and check for that on the handler page. If someone doesn't have the correct session variable, the request would then be denied.

#### Edit based on comments.

The price of a product is **not** a user input. It's not something to be inputted by the user, it's something to be **determined** by the server. You shouldn't have a hidden input containing the product price. Only the product ID, and take the price from a database.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to prevent [cross-origin request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). OWAST have a [cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) on the subject. The short version is: Store a randomly generated token in the user's session (or cookie) and in the form. If the submitted token doesn't match the stored one, then reject the submission.

That is only effective against a third party tricking a visitor into submitting data to your site. You can't do anything to stop users submitting arbitrary data. The closest you can come to that is to make sure that the user has permission to do whatever they are trying to do (e.g. if they submit a request to edit something with the id 23, then check that they have permission to edit id 23 before allowing the edit to complete).

Update in response to comment:

> Yes and sometime user will edit value of hidden input. Let's say amount before redirect to payment page etc

The user doesn't get to choose how much they should pay so don't put the payment amount in the form data. Put the ids of the items being ordered and the quantity of each, then calculate the cost on the server.